# Javascript not rendering using django

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following code in a template, using a javascript event calendar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCalendar = new JEC('myCalendar'); 
    myCalendar.showCalendar();
</script>
```

I am using django to create the site. The calendar shows when I open the html document my browswer, but the calendar does not render when I use the actual site, even though everything else that is included in the template (not shown here) comes up fine. Is there something I am missing here? Do I need to return the myCalendar object to the view in order for it to render properly? I've searched a lot for some solutions, but I can't find anything. Some documentation to point me in the right direction would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in Firebug/developer tool?

Comment: I'd give this comment +100000 if I could. Every time you don't check javascript problems with Firebug, a deity kills a small cute furry animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide the static content to the user. You need to follow all of these step:-

1) Check in the settings.py static_dir refers to the directory containing your static files
2) Static folder has the read permission
3) From the view code you need to pass content_instance
4) Append {{STATIC_URL}} to the path reference of the js file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the first line. Check out how to [manage static content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in Django. That first line should look something more like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}calendar.js"></script>
```